# I am about to become a black belt, how can I make an impression?

Tags: tae-kwon-do

Finally, after a long journey, and still more, I will finally be a first degree black belt (If I pass, Taekwondo). For a black belt ceremony, are there any must-does to pass? How can I further my skill after this too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For first degree black belts, it will vary between different arts and instructors if there is a ceremony and if there is what form it takes. Our art has something we call the Soap and Candle ceremony, but we walk you through it beforehand and we don't take away a rank if you mess it up.

As far as for what you can do after, just keep going and learning. As the other poster says, you've graduated high school and now the real learning begins. As you progress in black belt ranks, start looking at other programs (weapons, tournaments, targeted self defense seminars, and so forth) that interest you and get involved. Look where you can give back to the art and the people coming after you. Making sure that you build your art to keep it going is more of a responsibility the higher you go in rank.

Answer (score 4):

You too will learn someday, that getting your black belt (1st dan) is the start of the journey. Everything before was just an introduction.

But as far as you question goes, different schools will have differing ceremonies. Ask a fellow black belt, or your instructor.